# Web-API, DelegatingHandler and security. Principal is reset in Controller

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, iprincipal

I've a [DelegatingHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler.aspx) in my Web-API service that, based on the headers provided, set a custom IPrincipal (ServicePrincipal) on the Thread.CurrentPrincipal and on the HttpContext.Current.User. This is all done on a call to [SendAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler.sendasync.aspx).

However, when the call get's into the Controller, the User property, the HttpContext.User and the Thread.CurrentPrincipal have all been mysteriously set to a RolePrincipal.

Does anyone know either what I'm doing wrong, or how to prevent the additional principal being set?

Thanks,
Kieron

Comment: Make sure rolemanager is disabled

Comment: It's better...the HttpContext.User is now correct, but the Thread.CurrentPrincipal is still a RolePrincipal - so the request still fails to authenticate...

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution?  I have a tangental problem that might benefit from your solution.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but I was having a similar issue trying to get the current user from within a function overriding `DelegatingHandler.SendAsync()`. The `IPrincipal` object doesn't seem to get initialized until after the call to `base.SendAsync()`. After that line is called, the `IPrincipal` object should have the user information.

I used `request.GetRequestContext().Principal` to retrieve it, but I'm guessing `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` would work too.